# tf.vectorized_map does not concat variable length tensors (InvalidArgumentError: PartialTensorShape: Incompatible shapes during merge)

Tags: python, tensorflow, vectorization, tensorflow2.0, tensor

I am running into a "InvalidArgumentError:  PartialTensorShape: Incompatible shapes during merge" error when I try to tf.concat two tensors who's shapes are dependent on the function input within the vectorized function (even though the output shape is the same for each a,b pair). Below is an example of the situation

```
import tensorflow as tf 

def test_fn(inputs):
    a,b = inputs
    out = tf.concat([tf.ones(a),tf.zeros(b)],0)
    return out

a = tf.constant([5,4,3,2])
b = tf.constant([5,6,7,8])
x_a = tf.vectorized_map(test_fn,(a,b))
```

I am looking for an explanation of why the error is happening.

Note: I noticed in the source code the comment "- The shape and dtype of any intermediate or output tensors in the computation of `fn` should not depend on the input to `fn`." which seems to be the scenario here. Is there a workaround that can still take advantage of the vectorization?

Using `x_a = tf.map_fn(test_fn,(a,b),fn_output_signature=tf.TensorSpec((10,)))` works but doesn't parallelize.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are passing a tensor to `tf.ones` and `tf.zeros` instead of a shape. For example, if you pass the tensor `a` to `tf.ones`, it will be interpreted as the shape resulting in a tensor with the shape `(5, 4, 3, 2)`. That is probably not what you want. Try something like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf 

def test_fn(inputs):
  a, b = inputs
  out = tf.stack([tf.ones_like(a), tf.zeros_like(b)], 0)
  return out

a = tf.constant([5,4,3,2])
b = tf.constant([5,6,7,8])
x_a = tf.vectorized_map(test_fn,(a,b))
x_a = tf.transpose(x_a)
print(x_a)
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[[1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0]], shape=(2, 4), dtype=int32)
```

Note that you have to use `tf.stack` instead of `tf.concat` because TF does not currently support scalar concatenation when using `tf.vectorized_map`. Check out the [limitations](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/vectorized_map) of `tf.vectorized_map` here.